# How does Vulnerability interact with multiple instances of bonus damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, attack, vulnerability

Suppose I have *vulnerable 5 fire* on a monster and I hit it with a basic melee attack. This melee attack comes with an extra 3 fire damage from Swordmage's Burning Blade, and an extra 1d4 fire damage due to a feature of the *Malec-Keth Janissary* paragon path.

Does this monster then suffer 5 bonus fire damage from its fire vulnerability, or 10 damage since it was hit by two different instances of fire damage?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're talking about the Malec-Keth Janissary paragon path. Vulnerability only works once per instance of damage, because all the damage is happening at once, Vulnerability is only applied once.

Comment: Ah i see thank you very much for your quick response